# Force numeric keyboard on Mobile and not break validation in Chrome

Tags: validation, google-chrome, xpages

Here is my situation.  I need to show a numeric keyboard on a mobile device.  I know that to do that you need the attribute type="number" on the input tag.

I also am using a validator to check for various conditions.  I have discovered that in Chrome ONLY, the validator will not fire if the type is set to "number".  I have tried attempting to change the attribute with jQuery, and it will not change.  I know my jQuery is correct, because if I change it from "type" to "type1" it adds the attribute.

With that said, I don't think it will make a difference, because if I inspect element, and manually change the type from "text" to "number" the validation breaks.  Works fine in Firefox and IE, perhaps a bug in Chrome.  It might have something to do with the fact that Chrome uses those handy up/down arrows, but those don't help me if validation is skipped.  If anyone knows a workaround, I would love to hear it.

Additonal Info:  Chrome is up to date.  disableClientSideValidation is set to true, since I hate alerts and am using 'display-errors' to show error msgs right on the page.  The edit box is bound to a field in a managed bean of data type "String".  Also, I cannot add the attribute using the 'attrs', if I do so it is ignored.  For more details on the validation see this blog post: http://notesspeak.blogspot.com/2013/08/the-benefits-of-using-validator-in.html

Comment: Are the numbers integers or decimals? If they are integers you use type='tel' for the field. I am not sure if that circumvents the validation issue, but the entry of numbers from a mobile phone are much easier with the telephone keyboard provided by most mobile OS than the numeric keyboard.

Comment: Peter, I have considered that, in the some instances it will work, but in others I will need the user to enter a currency amount.  I have already said in a meeting that I will make this work, and I am hoping not have to backtrack.

Comment: Still looking for an answer here if anyone has a clue.  BTW, as Peter suggested "Tel" works great, and validation works fine, but that is only good for integers.

Answer (score 0):

What's your code? I think that's going to help identify the cause.

If disableClientSideValidation is set to true, the browser shouldn't have any impact on validation. Server-side validation doesn't know or care about the browser type.

Custom validators do not run if the field is blank. If you need to force the field to be entered, you need to add a required validator as well.

Comment: I am not using a custom validator, but a "validator".  See the blog post linked above for the code, which is derived from your code on an SO you helped me with 2 months ago (thanks again!).  It actually DOES validate w/o a required validator EXCEPT on Chrome when type="number".  I know it sounds crazy but it is true.